# Are these definitions equivalent for a subbasis of the product space?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to determine how the definition of the product topology for $Y^X$ I found in some notes from math.bard.edu relates is the same as the product topology defined by Munkres.

One of the things I read is that the sets of a subbasis can be described as $$S(x,U)=\{f\in Y^{X}:f(x)\in U\}$$ being $U$ open and $U\subset Y$, and $x\in X$.

The first issue I have here is how to relate this definition to the more common definition of basis for the product topology, as far as I know the subbasis would be given by the sets of the form
$$\{\pi_{1}^{-1}(U):\text{U open in X}\}\cup\{\pi_{1}^{-1}(V):\text{V open in Y}\}$$

I really can't tell how to adapt the former definition for the product topology of $X\times Y$ to the product topology of $Y^{X}$ as it was stated first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $Y^X$ denotes the set of all functions $X→Y$. Since a function does nothing more than assign to each $x\in X$ a $y\in Y$, a function $f:X→Y$ can be seen as an $x$-indexed tuple 
$$(y_x)_{x\in X}=(f(x))_{x\in X}$$
and the set of all such tuples is the product $\prod_X Y$, the product of 
"$X$-many" copies of $Y$.
There are projections $\pi_x:\prod_X Y→Y$, sending each tuple $f=(f(x))_{x\in X}$ to its value at $x$, so $π_x(f)=f(x)$.
Now the subbasis of $Y^X$ is given by sets 
$$S(x,U)=π_x^{-1}(U)=\{f \in Y^X\mid π_x(f)\in U\}$$
where $x$ ranges over all elements in $X$, and $U$ ranges over all open sets in $Y$. But
$$\{f \in Y^X\mid π_x(f)\in U\}=\{f\in Y^X\mid f(x)\in U\}$$